# Base 64 encode Bitmap from WX Python

Tags: python, bitmap, wxpython, base64

I am trying to send a screenshot over a network via Python Wx. I am able to take a screenshot and save it to the filesystem, but I do not want to save it. I want to get the Base 64 code and send it without saving.

Here is my current attempt:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import requests
import socket
import time
import wx
import base64

def checkServer():
    sesh = requests.session()
    app = wx.App(False)
    while True:
        s = wx.ScreenDC()
        w, h = s.Size.Get()
        b = wx.EmptyBitmap(w, h)
        m = wx.MemoryDCFromDC(s)
        m.SelectObject(b)
        m.Blit(0, 0, w, h, s, 0, 0)
        m.SelectObject(wx.NullBitmap)

        #outputs: <wx._gdi.Bitmap; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'wxBitmap *' at 0x2001640> >
        #print b 

        #Does NOT Work, outputs: TypeError: must be convertible to a buffer, not Bitmap
        #base64img = base64.b64encode(b) 

        # Works, but not what I want to do
        #b.SaveFile("screenshot.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)

        hostname = socket.gethostname()
        url = 'http://localhost/callcenter/monitor/post.php'
        payload = {
            'host' : hostname,
            #'image' : base64img
        }
        headers = {
            'Connection' : "keep-alive", 
            'Content-Type' : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        }
        r = sesh.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers, allow_redirects=False, verify=False)
        content = r.text
        print content
        time.sleep(5)

checkServer()
```

How can I get the Base 64 code in a string from the bitmap `b`?

**EDIT**

I also tried:

```
buf=io.BytesIO()
b.CopyToBuffer(buf)
base64img = base64.b64encode(buf)
print base64img
```

and got this:

```
  File "./main.py", line 51, in <module>
    checkServer()
  File "./main.py", line 29, in checkServer
    b.CopyToBuffer(buf)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode/wx/_gdi.py", line 740, in CopyToBuffer
    return _gdi_.Bitmap_CopyToBuffer(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: expected a readable buffer object
```

**Edit 2**

Tried this:

```
buf=bytearray()
b.CopyToBuffer(buf)
base64img = base64.b64encode(buf)
print base64img
```

And got something different this time:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 51, in <module>
    checkServer()
  File "./main.py", line 29, in checkServer
    b.CopyToBuffer(buf)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode/wx/_gdi.py", line 740, in CopyToBuffer
    return _gdi_.Bitmap_CopyToBuffer(*args, **kwargs)
ValueError: Invalid data buffer size.
```

Comment: afaik you need to save it in the file format you want and then base64encode the file contents ... there might be a way to output the bitmap image content to a stream

Comment: Does this work? `buf=io.BytesIO(); b.CopyToBuffer(buf); base64.b64encode(buf)`

Comment: there you go ... I figured there was some way to dump the image to a stream ... but I doubt thats quite what OP wants... unless the other end also understands wxBitmaps  ... I think OP must save as png and then base64encode the file contents

Comment: @Kolmar no, it doesn't: TypeError: expected a readable buffer object

Comment: @Kolmar, didn't work either. See edited question for the outputs.

Comment: @Kolmar Thanks, but that didn't work either. Same error.

Comment: @Kolmar Thank you for your persistence! That didn't work either but I got a different error this time. See second edit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
base64img = base64.b64encode(b.ConvertToImage().GetData())
```

Comment: at `buf=bytearray(b.GetSize())` i get 
`ValueError: byte must be in range(0, 256)`

Comment: Heck yes! Looks like it worked, just have to decode and verify, thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: @Adelphia No problem. Mind you, it seems to require 1 or 2 copies of the bitmap data. `GetDataBuffer()` on Image may also work and require 1 copy operation less ( http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Image-class.html#GetDataBuffer )

Comment: how do I provide multiple copies? It looks like it's working but it's not decoding properly. `GetDataBuffer()` didn't work either. This printed on the screen with no traceback: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Comment: @Adelphia I don't understand what is the problem currently. The data can't be decoded back? To decode you most likely need to unbase64 the data, and use `wx.ImageFromBuffer` or `SetData` on some Image object. Now that I think of it a better method would be  instead of `GetData` to use `Image.SaveStream` with `io.BytesIO()` as stream. You can provide it a type, and base64 encode `stream.read()`. Than you can read it back with `wx.ImageFromStream`. By multiple copies I meant that this may be slower and require more memory than other potential approaches, but further research is needed to be sure

Comment: I am saving the Base64 data to a MySQL database Longtext field and displaying it in a webpage via `<img src="data:image/bmp;base64,..." />` This is not displaying anything in the browser. I also tried copying the raw data into an online converter and that didn't display properly either.

I will try your suggestion and report back.

Comment: That's probably because `GetData` gives only an array of pixel values, it's not really an image encoded in any specific format. If you want to save it to be readable in some format like bmp or jpeg try `s=io.BytesIO(); b.ConvertToImage().SaveStream(s, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_BMP); base64.b64encode(s.read())` (or some other BITMAP_TYPE_* constant, JPEG or PNG would probably be better suited for a webpage), or even better use `SaveMimeStream` method, to which you provide the actual MIME string (like `image/png`, etc.), with which you are going to show the image in the webpage.